# How can i validate recaptcha with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

my function in js have this code:

```
$.ajax({
                                url: "ajax.php",
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: 'act=newAccount&email=' + email + '&password=' + password  + '&first-name=' + firstName + '&last-name=' + lastName + '&company-name=' + companyName,
                                success: function(data) 
                                {
                                    json = JSON.parse(data);
                                    if (json === true)
                                    {
                                        console.log("data");
                                        $("#new-account-form")[0].reset();
                                        window.location.replace('login.php');
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $(".error-message span").html('Your regestry failed. Please, insert valid data.');
                                        $('.error-message').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                                            $('.error-message').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

now, i want validate recaptha in my ajax.php but i dont know how i do...

thanks you all

Comment: BTW, in my opinion the code doesn't clarify the question, so you could delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a Captcha images' displayer and some code to validate it. I recommend **Securimage**, it worked fine for me, and it is so easy to implement. Have a look at it at http://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/quickstart-guide/

Comment: but i just want validate recaptcha in ajax.php

Comment: Unfortunately, it's impossible to give a simple answer to your question: The image with the Captcha image, the text the user writes and the validation: all three things get together. You can't validate a Captcha input text without knowing which image-text was shown to the user. I recommend you to have a careful look at http://www.phpcaptcha.org